# Install Multiple EXE files in folder

Tags: batch-file

I've a .bat file that I use to install multiple Microsoft hotfixes and it's working good. But I need to modify this code in order to work with .exe software.

Can any please assist me on this?

My batch file is:

```js
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
PUSHD %~dp0
FOR %%A IN (-KB.MSU) DO (
    CALL :SUB %%~nA
    ECHO= Installing KB!KB_NUM!
    >NUL TIMEOUT /t 3
    WUSA "%%~fA" /quiet /norestart
)
ECHO= == Press any key to restart ==
>NUL PAUSE
SHUTDOWN.EXE /r /t 0
GOTO :EOF

:SUB
SET "KB_NUM=%*"
FOR /F "DELIMS=-" %%B IN ("%KB_NUM:*-KB=%") DO SET "KB_NUM=%%B"
```

Answer (score 0):

All Setup.exe's are different. Some accept an answer file (.iss, .inf, etc), many accept various parameters. You will likely have to handle each .exe individually. You may get some good info by doing this from a command prompt:

```
YourSetup.exe /?
```

You may want your bat file to to check to see if the program in question is already installed first. Can you provide more details? What programs are you wanting to install?

If your intent is to get all important windows updates applied before installing other programs what I would do is allow the machine to restart if needed and use autologon.exe (from sysinternals) to restart this bat file on reboot so that you get subsequent updates that become available after installing the current set of updates. It may have to do that 2 or 3 times. Also beware that you should test your code across all the OS's that you may encounter. When it no longer reboots you clear the autologon stuff and resume installation of desired programs. Are some of them likely to require a reboot or additional updates (SQL).

BTW, your program above paints you into a corner in that in its present form you are not going to be able to get past the reboot question to continue without rebooting. Were you going to do something else so that you could continue without reboot?

You will not always get all updates installed on one pass. It's a bit of work but what you want to do can probably be done.